# What protocols/ports to open for WinSCP

Tags: windows, sftp, openwrt

Which ports (and/or protocols) should be given priority for WinSCP to connect to a *nix machine?

Details:

I have a Windows client running WinSCP, which connects through a WRT54 router (running Tomato) to a remote Ubuntu server. The Tomato router has Quality of Service options which allow me to specify what ports and protocols get priority.

What settings do I need to add to classify WinSCP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use the TCP destination port of 22 to classify the traffic (with optionally the destination IP of the server).  The source port will change and not always be the same.  Ports are part of the TCP header and destination IP is of course part of the IP header.

The port SSH is listening on the server doesn't have to be 22, but that is the default pot for the SSH protocol (including sftp).  It wouldn't be different from the default if you didn't have to change the port in winscp when setting up the connection.

Comment: -1 for not a complete answer:  The destination port will not always be 22.  It will be dependent on what has been set on the Ubuntu box.

Comment: But in that case, it would be impossible to answer the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SCP or SFTP (which is most likely) then port 22 TCP will be used as the connection will be using the SSH protocol.